# Assets 2.0 (P&T) not saving field setting for mutiple selection

Tags: add-on, assets, fieldtype

I downloaded Assets 2.0 and ran into an issue where the selection for the field "Allow multiple selections?" is not saved.
Thus I can't restrict the user to select only one file.

**UPDATE:** I'm using Expressionengine v2.5.3

Regards
Flo

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Bug (I've reported it yesterday) and P&T wrote me it will be fixed «ASAP»

See [Bug-Report](https://twitter.com/albuvee/status/291560667440361473) and [Reply from P&T](https://twitter.com/pixelandtonic/status/291571826788802560)